# Kendo UI grid undefined decimal

Tags: javascript, post, telerik, kendo-grid

This is my grid:

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '/Discount/Get',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "POST"
            },
            update: {
                url: '/Discount/Update',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "POST"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: '/Discount/Delete',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "POST"
            },
            create: {
                url: '/Discount/Add',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                console.log(operation);
                console.log(options);
                if (operation == "update") {
                    return { discountId: options.models.DiscountId, discountValue: options.models.DiscountValue }
                }
                if (operation == "create") {
                    return JSON.stringify({ discountValue: options.models.DiscountValue, topItemName: options.models.TopItemName });
                }
                if (operation == "destroy") {
                    return { discountId: options.models.DiscountId }
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "DiscountId",
                fields: {
                    DiscountId: { type: "number" },
                    TopItemName: { type: "string" },
                    DiscountValue: { type: "number" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
    height: 400,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
    {
        field: "TopItemName",
        filterable: true
    },
    {
        field: "DiscountValue",
        format: "{0:p0}",
        editor: function (container, options) {
            $("<input name='DiscountValue'>")
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoNumericTextBox(
              {
                  min: 0,
                  max: 1.0,
                  step: 0.01
              });
        }
    }],
    editable: true
});
```

In the grid I have a custom editor which will make the textbox to a percentage.

In my console.log when I make a create call and I got this

```
   Object {DiscountId: 0, TopItemName: "asdasd", DiscountValue: "0.05"}
```

So there is a value for `DiscountValue`. But still i get the error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DiscountValue' of undefined
```

Is this something about `DiscountValue` being a float value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DiscountValue' of undefined
```

This error doesn't mean there is no field 'DiscountValue', it means you are trying to read a property of an `undefined` variable.

So if the error is from here :

```
options.models.DiscountValue
```

It means `options.models` is undefined.

Your log output printed the definition of `options`, not `options.models`.
You might confound with `options.DiscountValue` ?